# BTRFS after multiple power outages bad checksum

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, data-recovery, btrfs

After multiple power outages, btrfs have bad checksums, is it possible to recover it?

Outages were on Dell R740xd with PERC H730P Adapter looks like the cache was unwritten.

now trying to recover in fedora with btrfs-progs v6.5.1

**DMESG** at mount

```
[ 7471.519489] BTRFS: device fsid 3e7baffe-c84f-4bf1-a830-84adb5899539 devid 1 transid 1197903 /dev/xvdb1 scanned by mount (1536)
[ 7471.524090] BTRFS info (device xvdb1): using crc32c (crc32c-intel) checksum algorithm
[ 7471.524099] BTRFS info (device xvdb1): disk space caching is enabled
[ 7481.606391] BTRFS info (device xvdb1): enabling ssd optimizations
[ 7481.629116] BTRFS warning (device xvdb1): checksum verify failed on logical 4317118464 mirror 1 wanted 0x4b93e5a3 found 0x743b8159 level 1
```

**mount** returns

```
mount: /temp: can't read superblock on /dev/xvdb1.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.
```

mount -o **ro,rescue=usebackuproot**  /dev/xvdb1 /temp/
give same output

**btrfs rescue super-recover -v /dev/xvdb1**

```
All Devices:
        Device: id = 1, name = /dev/xvdb1

Before Recovering:
        [All good supers]:
                device name = /dev/xvdb1
                superblock bytenr = 65536

                device name = /dev/xvdb1
                superblock bytenr = 67108864

                device name = /dev/xvdb1
                superblock bytenr = 274877906944

        [All bad supers]:

All supers are valid, no need to recover
```

**btrfs restore /dev/xvdb1 /temp/**

```
checksum verify failed on 4317118464 wanted 0x4b93e5a3 found 0x743b8159
checksum verify failed on 4317118464 wanted 0x4b93e5a3 found 0x743b8159
Csum didn't match
ERROR: search for next directory entry failed: -5
```

Full super block info

```
[root@localhost |]# btrfs inspect-internal dump-super -f /dev/xvdb1
superblock: bytenr=65536, device=/dev/xvdb1
---------------------------------------------------------
csum_type               0 (crc32c)
csum_size               4
csum                    0xb72b3f47 [match]
bytenr                  65536
flags                   0x1
                        ( WRITTEN )
magic                   _BHRfS_M [match]
fsid                    3e7baffe-c84f-4bf1-a830-84adb5899539
metadata_uuid           00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
label
generation              1197903
root                    4328472576
sys_array_size          97
chunk_root_generation   1197057
root_level              1
chunk_root              1097728
chunk_root_level        1
log_root                0
log_root_transid (deprecated)   0
log_root_level          0
total_bytes             2147482599424
bytes_used              1786107740160
sectorsize              4096
nodesize                16384
leafsize (deprecated)   16384
stripesize              4096
root_dir                6
num_devices             1
compat_flags            0x0
compat_ro_flags         0x0
incompat_flags          0x161
                        ( MIXED_BACKREF |
                          BIG_METADATA |
                          EXTENDED_IREF |
                          SKINNY_METADATA )
cache_generation        1197903
uuid_tree_generation    1197903
dev_item.uuid           8c6fd39f-1924-4314-9454-4c4a91999731
dev_item.fsid           3e7baffe-c84f-4bf1-a830-84adb5899539 [match]
dev_item.type           0
dev_item.total_bytes    2147482599424
dev_item.bytes_used     1855438454784
dev_item.io_align       4096
dev_item.io_width       4096
dev_item.sector_size    4096
dev_item.devid          1
dev_item.dev_group      0
dev_item.seek_speed     0
dev_item.bandwidth      0
dev_item.generation     0
sys_chunk_array[2048]:
        item 0 key (FIRST_CHUNK_TREE CHUNK_ITEM 1048576)
                length 4194304 owner 2 stripe_len 65536 type SYSTEM|single
                io_align 4096 io_width 4096 sector_size 4096
                num_stripes 1 sub_stripes 0
                        stripe 0 devid 1 offset 1048576
                        dev_uuid 8c6fd39f-1924-4314-9454-4c4a91999731
backup_roots[4]:
        backup 0:
                backup_tree_root:       4328472576      gen: 1197903    level: 1
                backup_chunk_root:      1097728 gen: 1197057    level: 1
                backup_extent_root:     4328636416      gen: 1197903    level: 3
                backup_fs_root:         4379639808      gen: 1197899    level: 2
                backup_dev_root:        4377640960      gen: 1197903    level: 1
                csum_root:      4379656192      gen: 1197903    level: 2
                backup_total_bytes:     2147482599424
                backup_bytes_used:      1786107740160
                backup_num_devices:     1

        backup 1:
                backup_tree_root:       4317069312      gen: 1197900    level: 1
                backup_chunk_root:      1097728 gen: 1197057    level: 1
                backup_extent_root:     4317429760      gen: 1197900    level: 3
                backup_fs_root:         4379639808      gen: 1197899    level: 2
                backup_dev_root:        4325916672      gen: 1197900    level: 1
                csum_root:      4327030784      gen: 1197900    level: 2
                backup_total_bytes:     2147482599424
                backup_bytes_used:      1786107740160
                backup_num_devices:     1

        backup 2:
                backup_tree_root:       4328636416      gen: 1197901    level: 1
                backup_chunk_root:      1097728 gen: 1197057    level: 1
                backup_extent_root:     4328652800      gen: 1197901    level: 3
                backup_fs_root:         4379639808      gen: 1197899    level: 2
                backup_dev_root:        4378968064      gen: 1197901    level: 1
                csum_root:      4379738112      gen: 1197901    level: 2
                backup_total_bytes:     2147482599424
                backup_bytes_used:      1786107740160
                backup_num_devices:     1

        backup 3:
                backup_tree_root:       4317069312      gen: 1197902    level: 1
                backup_chunk_root:      1097728 gen: 1197057    level: 1
                backup_extent_root:     4317429760      gen: 1197902    level: 3
                backup_fs_root:         4379639808      gen: 1197899    level: 2
                backup_dev_root:        4326195200      gen: 1197902    level: 1
                csum_root:      4327096320      gen: 1197902    level: 2
                backup_total_bytes:     2147482599424
                backup_bytes_used:      1786107740160
                backup_num_devices:     1
```

Have dd copy of the disk so have opportunity to try multiple fix ways.
Data was backed up, but this brick has the latest data for 1 month.

Comment: what does `Disk are in xen` even mean?

Comment: Xen's a virtualisation platform. I'm not familiar with disk devices being xvdb, so its possible they're disk images atop a physical raid, which in situations of powerloss might make things more challenging.

Comment: Hardware HDDs -> HW RAID5 in perc-> XFS FS on top of that raid 5 in xen host-> virtual machine with block device with btrfs in virtual machine.